# Facebook comment social plugin not displaying comments?

Tags: comments, facebook-social-plugins

I'm using Facebook's comments social plugin for a site. It's pulling in the comment count, but not the actual comments. It works just fine if I change the data-href to something else (like http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/), but not the site that I'm using. Which is weird, because it worked without any issues a few days ago.

Has anyone else had this issue or know of a solution? I'm using the HTML5 code found [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone stumbles on this, there was a bug in facebook's code. They've resolved the issue. If it happens to anyone else, you can let them know by posting  [here](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/trending/).